# Upload video to Blob Storage using Azure Function

Tags: azure, flutter, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my app I would like my users to upload local videos, which I would want to store in the Blob Storage. But I would like to achieve this by using the Azure Functions. Is this possible? If so, I couldn't find any resource that could point me in the right direction. If not what would be the ideal way to achieve this. I am building the app using flutter, for which we do not yet have the SDK's. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no SDK available for **Dart**. You'll have to make a back-end part running in **.NET**, **Java**, **JavaScript** or **Python** in order to use Azure Functions.

But you can use the **Azure Storage REST API** to store the videos as blobs using a **Storage Account.**

Take a look at the official reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/). Using this, you'll be able to store the videos using Http.

Also, [this tutorial](http://mikaelsand.se/2019/11/simple-how-to-upload-a-file-to-azure-storage-using-rest-api/) might be useful.

The fella here is using the **File Service** instead the Blob Service.
A point of interest is that you have to be in mind some limitations, not that it's impossible to do what you want to, but is good to be aware:

> There are limitations to the storage service.
> [...] You can only upload 4mb “chunks” per upload. So if your
> files exeed 4mb you have to split them into parts. If you are a good
> programmer you can make use of tasks and await to start multiple
> threads. Please consult the Azure limits documentation to see if any
> other restrictions apply.

Comment: Ended up writing the back-end using JavaScript in the Azure functions. Thanks for the help ;)